# Consola no muestra el contenido completo de la variable

Tags: firefox, dev-tools

Por medio de un var_dump quiero extraer la consulta que se almacena en una variable, pero la consola de Firefox no muestra todo el contenido, en su lugar muestra una pequeña fracción y el largo de caracteres restantes.

[image: Respuesta en consola]

He probado revisar la respuesta de consola en diferentes navegadores (Firefox, Chrome, Brave, Edge) siempre con el mismo resultado, he reinstalado los navegadores sin obtener diferencias, desde Firefox ya revise la configuración del ‘devtools.netmonitor.responseBodyLimit’ se encuentre en 0 sin tener cambios.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, el numero de caracteres no se muestra completo porque se encuentra instalado xdebug y no se tenían las configuraciones para permitir mas caracteres. Desde este enlace se encuentra la configuración para evitar este inconveniente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998490/how-to-get-xdebug-var-dump-to-show-full-object-array